# Running in the same thread, yet CalledFromWrongThreadexception

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio

Compiler says that ppp can only be touched by the thread which created it, altough it's been created a line above.
What could possibly be the problem?

```
public void init(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                elet = 10;
                InetAddress addr;
                Socket sock = new Socket("46.101.150.158", 1035);
                addr = sock.getInetAddress();
                DataOutputStream ki = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                ki.write('a');
                ki.flush();
                final BufferedReader be = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                lekert = String.valueOf(be.readLine());
                Log.d("Szo",lekert);
                kiir = "";
                word = lekert;
                tomb = new Boolean[lekert.length()-1];
                for(int i = 0; i < lekert.length()-1;++i){
                    tomb[i] = false;
                }
                tomb[0] = true;
                tomb[lekert.length()-2] = true;
                for(int i = 0 ; i < lekert.length()-1;++i){
                    if(tomb[i]){
                        kiir += lekert.charAt(i);
                    }else{
                        kiir += '_';
                    }
                }
                TextView ppp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                ppp.setText(kiir);
                Button check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
                if(elet == 0){
                    check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide us with a minimal example that reproduces your error and that we could easily copy paste and run.

Comment: Show them, line of the error, and the stack. After all this is SO ;)

Answer (score 2):

> altough it's been created a line above

No, it has not. You called `findViewById()`. `findViewById()` does not *create* anything. It *finds* a widget from your existing view hierarchy. That view hierarchy was created somewhere else (e.g., `setContentView()` in your `onCreate()` method of your activity).

Either switch to using `AsyncTask` (with your widget-updating code in `onPostExecute()`) or otherwise arrange to update your `TextView` and `Button` on the main application thread.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call ui methods you must call `runOnUiThread`. So try to change it from this

```
TextView ppp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
ppp.setText(kiir);
Button check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
if(elet == 0){
    check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

to this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextView ppp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ppp.setText(kiir);
        Button check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        if(elet == 0){
           check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```